# Why does asset building using mini-css-extract-plugin work in development but fail in Heroku build process?

Tags: css, heroku, webpack, assets, precompile

Trying to deploy to Heroku with a node.js and ruby buildpack

Git push to Heroku invokes the buildpacks and the rake asset:precompile task is run

Unfortunately this task is failing during the "Compiling" phase with the error below shown for each css/scss asset file to be deployed

```
ERROR in ./app/assets/stylesheets/base.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
at ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.apply (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:17:37)
at /tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalsPlugin.js:16:63
at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
at /tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1028:23
at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
at Compiler.compile (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1025:28)
at Compiler.runAsChild (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:495:8)
at Object.pitch (/tmp/build_4b756368/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js:126:17)
@ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 6:0-42
```

Comment: Struggling to understand how it can be so hard to do anything with Rails these days with all this dependency on node and yarn etc. Seems to be so many problems with versioning - this is the third major problem I have hit trying to do a "standard deployment" to Heroku. It's supposed to be a rapid development environment but seems to be very problematic to get anything to work at all. Sigh.

Comment: OK, this is a bummer. Seems like no-one can help with this and I have no idea how to proceed other than get rid of the whole Webpacker thing for assets - it seems so unstable and poorly understood that perhaps that is the best for now until the whole Rails and Webpacker world stabilises. The only reason I got into this situation I think was because I was having trouble getting Sprockets and Webpacker to co-exist but back to the drawing board it is then. I still don't understand why my setup works locally and in Codeship but not on Heroku - I guess there are just so many variables.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue. I can't find anything online about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same issues and I upgraded to the pre-release version of Webpacker following the instructions here:

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/6_0_upgrade.md

That fixed my issue and everything worked after that.

Comment: Thanks very much Dan. That is a great tip - I have had no luck to date and had virtually given up! I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I spent some time following the link you gave and on the face of things it looks like it will eventually lead to a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, right now my Dev environment is completely broken and I really have no clue about what asset files are supposed to be where.

I have:
app/assets folder with config, images and stylesheets subfolders
javascript/packs folder with application.css and application.js scaffold files
packs/entrypoints with application.js
packs which has another Sprockets application.js manifest and all my coffeescript files

Very confused about what should be where?

Comment: Revisited the Webpacker document and sorted out the folder structure to remove assets and javascript in favour of packs folder.

Had a lot of trouble with missing Babel modules but managed to yarn install a bunch that were missing but required (although the app used to work without them?)

Also had to rejig imports and comments in SASS files to get webpacker to compile which it now does but still cant get any of the CSS to take effect - listed in manifest file but just not working

Comment: Oh - I can see that the SASS has not been precompiled to CSS so that the public/packs/css/application.css file is not valid CSS

Comment: Fixed the SASS issue by renaming application.css to application.scss in entrypoints.
Dev environment now fixed but now trying to debug why assets are not built properly by Webpacker in Codeship CI environment. What a struggle.

Comment: I know I am documenting the journey here, but someone might find it useful.
I fixed my Codeship setup - my custom webpacker.yml was overwritten when Webpacker was installed in Codeship so added a line to restore it from a backup in my codeship_setup script:
cp config/codeship.webpacker.yml config/webpacker.yml

Comment: Finally got to the end of the pipeline and yes, happy days, the Webpacker compile works and the app is deployed to Heroku at last! Thanks very much Dan.